# What are the supported libraries in Python in Excel and how to query them

Tags: python, excel

I'm using the latest version of excel and want to know what libraries are supported by python in excel, what is the version of the specific library and how to check it, thank you

I checked the official documentation, but I didn't find it

Comment: https://www.excelpython.org/

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, on the Formulas tab, click the Initialization button to get the list of supported libraries. Then this python "formula" in Excel gives you the version of the numpy used:

```
np.__version__
```

1.23.5 as I write this

Answer (score 0):

Some core libraries are available by default and you can see them in the Initialization tab.
Apart from that, you may also import any other libraries available through Anaconda.
See: [Open-source libraries and Python in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/open-source-libraries-and-python-in-excel-c817c897-41db-40a1-b9f3-d5ffe6d1bf3e)